# C# - Generic method with linq parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I'm thinking of creating something like this:

```
Class.Method<OtherClass>(x => new Dictionary<string, string> { { nameof(x.Property), "Hello World!" } });
```

I'd like the Method to be void, but somehow I can't get this done. I understand that this signature is

```
public static void Method<T>(Func<T, Dictionary<string, string>> func)
```

but I don't want to use the dictionary az a TResult. All I want is to have a dictionary as an input and fill the keys from the T type. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Could you clarify, are you trying to populate the dictionary based on an input function?

Comment: Maybe you could show what you plan to do in the body of the method?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, you're trying to provide a function that populates keys for an existing dictionary. If that's the case, you could do something like this:

```
public static void Method<T>(Action<T, IDictionary<string, string>> mergeAction);
```

This can be called like this:

```
MyClass.Method<OtherClass>((input, dict) => { dict[nameof(input.Property)] = "hello world"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Func<T, TResult>` where `TResult` should return void must be declared as an `Action<T>`